# Can we use as continuous vairables the mean of discrete variables?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

For example basketball teams' scores are discrete variables, we are sure.

However, if I want to use the mean (average) score of 100 basketball teams, can I say it is a continuous variable? Is the average number of points scored a continuous or discrete variable?

Comment: The average of many discrete values has so many possible distinct values that it would be common, and defensible, to regard it as *approximately* continuous. The question is when you need to emphasise *approximately* and when you don't.

Comment: There's a distinction between what it *is* (discrete) and what it's reasonable to treat it as if it were (which is not really adding anything to what Nick said but perhaps expressing it in a different way may help)